# react Native JWT-auth Error fetching api

Tags: javascript, react-native

***React Native JWT-auth Error fetching api***

I am trying to fetch user detail by using jwt-auth, by following method.

```
login() {
    alert(this.state.UserName);
    fetch (Api+''+'/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token',{
        method: "POST",
        username: this.state.UserName,
        password: this.state.Password
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) =>{
          console.log("LoginData:-" + JSON.stringify(responseData));
       }).done();
    }
}
```

and getting error:-

```
{
    "code":"[jwt_auth] empty_username",
    "message":"<strong>ERROR</strong>: The username field is empty.",
    "data":{"status":403}
}
```

If anyone Knows Please help.

Answer (score 1):

*I dont think you need the answer anymore as its been an year posting this question, Still if anyone else need*

As shown in the [networking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network) tab of React Native You need to pass **data into body** and **JWT token in headers** like below, this is working for me so have a look and update if there is any problem into this

```
login(){
    fetch(Api+''+'/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'JWT '+<token> // There will be different type of authorization like Bearer, JWT, Basic
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: this.state.UserName,
        password: this.state.Password
      }),
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        console.log("LoginData:-" + JSON.stringify(responseData));
    }).done();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your API is using basic Authentication you need to add username and password as a Authentication header

**Example**

```
const base64 = require('base-64');
login() {
    alert(this.state.UserName);
    fetch (Api+''+'/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token',{
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode(this.state.UserName+ ":" + this.state.Password)
        }
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) =>{
          console.log("LoginData:-" + JSON.stringify(responseData));
       }).done();
    }
}
```